# php if else multiple lines shorthand

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator, shorthand

I would like to conditionally execute two functions:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    (strtolower($message) == $row['question'])
        ? msg($row['answer']) && update($row['question'])
        : '';
```

but this code is not working.

Comment: *What* is not working? If msg() returns false, update() won't fire of course.

Comment: What is the definition of msg() and update()? Those could be causing the problem. Since you are saying `if(strtolower($message) == $row['question']) { msg($row['answer']) && update($row['question'])} else { return ''}`

Comment: Syntax is correct, no errors. Functions msg(); and update(); are simply mysql_update. This code without update(); function works correctly. When they are two functions, second function not working.

Comment: Try `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: Like @Bert said, the `update()` function won't fire since you are using a tenary operator and a tenary operator uses only simple inputs. The only thing you can do is write another function maybe `msg_upate()` that wraps `msg()` and `update()` with their parameters and change the statement to: `(strtolower($message) == $row['question']) ? msg_update($row['answer']) : '';`

Comment: You really REALLY need to [read the manual on ternaries](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and heed the warning about them

Comment: Inserted line breaks for easier reading; tightened wording.

Answer (score 1):

Shorthand only works for one-line statements.  Since your **if** statement contains two lines, shorthand does not work.  Usually **while** loops are formatted as follows:

```
while (/* condition */)
{
    // code to be executed
}
```

Your ternary expression is also incorrect; it should be written as follows:

```
(/* condition */) ? /* if true do this */ : /* if false do this */
```

In the second part of the ternary statement (`?:`), you use the conditional operator `&&`, which compares two boolean expressions. As I understand it, your intention of the use of `&&` is to execute two lines, which is incorrect. Refer to the documentation: [PHP Docs (Comparison operators)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

You need to write the **while** loop with braces, because your **if** statement contains multiple lines of code, as follows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
    if (strtolower($message) == $row['question'])
    {
        msg($row['answer']);
        update($row['question']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you need to use the shorthand code to do this?

The following would be rather more readable and also when you (or someone else) comes to update/change/review/debug the code sometime in the future it will be much more obvious what the intended outcomes were.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (strtolower($message) == $row['question']) {
        msg($row['answer']);
        update($row['question']);
    }
}
```

Usually the shortnened ?: version is reserved only for the very simplest conditions and actions.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function `msg_update()` that wraps `msg()` and `update()`:

```
function msg_update($row) {
    msg($row);
    update($row);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) (strtolower($message) == $row['question']) ? msg_update($row['answer']) : '';
```

This is because a tenary operator takes only simple operations. Hope that works for you.